# How to fetch data using wagmi without user wallet?

Tags: ethers.js, react, wagmi

Is it possible to use the useContractRead hooks to get contract data without the user connecting their wallet? I see no option to do a read without a user connecting first in wagmi.

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility of using `readContract` from `wagmi/core`.

```
import { readContract } from '@wagmi/core'
 
const data = await readContract({
  address: '0xecb504d39723b0be0e3a9aa33d646642d1051ee1',
  abi: wagmigotchiABI,
  functionName: 'getHunger',
})
```

See more:
https://wagmi.sh/core/actions/readContract